# Can the Joomla jConfig be extended with an administrator plugin?

Tags: joomla2.5

I'm trying to add some external configuration parameters to a new J2.5 site, and before I resort to hacks, I want to know if it is possible to write a plugin that will actually integrate with, or extend the jConfig object.

I have been googling, and cannot find any discussion or example of such a thing - only component or module configuration, so wanted to know if anyone had attempted this, or knew of a "native" way of accomplishing it.

Note - We'd accomplished this in earlier versions by way of a system plugin that set a global variable to make the information available, but we're hoping to include it in the Joomla Global Configuration to be able to use native Joomla config logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't.  With a plugin it's only possible to override some minor classes, when the plugins files are first loaded (which would be the first hook for our custom code) JConfig is already loaded along with another 40 classes.

You could however extend it once it's loaded, add your parameters, save, and those should be persisted when the user saves from the backend, and made available in the following requests. Provided you're not saving too many it could work fine.

Otherwise just put your parameters in the component (which would be the standard Joomla way).

Comment: Thank you good sir...sometimes you can't see the trees for the forest.  I wish it were as simple as putting it in the component.  We've got a large number of custom components/modules/plugins that are installed in a variety of combinations They all use a database and a couple of other settings aside from the core Joomla stuff.  This is why I was looking for a "sweet spot" to put them in a single place, rather than in any number of places depending on the site setup.